# Plotting live data from arduino with matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, arduino, live

I am trying to build a robot with an arduino. In my code, i am reading sensor values and calculate variables. I want to send these data to my computer in order to plot and have full control of my robot movement. I would also like to have a graphical interface(GUI). For example, i want to read data continuously and when a  button is pushed, a window with a plot will open.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this for *Santa Claus*? Then let me add that [I'd like to have a **cat**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Comment: Wemcome to SO. Get the data with serial communication and create a GUI with guide. There are many tutorials out there for these tasks. Come back when you have a concrete and precise question for which you tried something but cannot find an answer with a reasonable search. Have fun with your project !

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately for you Ι have done the exact same project as the one that you are describing. You can check my solution in my Github profile here : https://github.com/kmonahopoulos/Monakons-UGV-radar-robot. I have included all the necessary files, also including a description and an implementation circuit. My approach was to use two X-bee modules for the communication, but you can also do it through the serial port using a simple USB cable. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit a broad question indeed.

For data plotting, there are really many tools you can pick from.

Let me start by promoting my own work in this are: https://github.com/windelbouwman/lognplot

Next to this, there is a good post with an overview of tools located here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1180/serial-data-plotting-programs